# How to create elasticsearch aggregation using Java API on scala

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

I am new to programming and I want to get the sum of power used in a month from a data stored in elasticsearch, I've used sense and got the value but still finding it hard using Java API in scala. This is what I did

```
POST /myIndext/myType/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
"aggs": {
"duration": {
"date_histogram": {
"field": "Day",
"interval": "month",
"format": "yyyy-MM-dd"},
"aggs": {
"Power_total": {
"sum": {
"field": "myField"
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

RESULT WAS

```
( "aggregations": {
      "duration": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key_as_string": "2017-01-01",
               "key": 1480550400000,
               "doc_count": 619,
               "myField": {
                  "value": 5218.066633789334
               }
            }
```

Then scala code is this

```
    val matchquery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("ID", configurate)

    val queryK = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("ID", configurate)

    val filterA = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("Day").gte("2017-01-02T00:00:05.383+0100").lte("2017-01-13T00:00:05.383+0100")
    val query = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(queryK, filteAr)
    val agg = AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("duration")
      .field("Day")
      .interval(DateHistogramInterval.MONTH)
      .minDocCount(0)
      .extendedBounds(new DateTime("2017-01-01T00:00:05.383+0100"), new DateTime("2017-01-13T00:00:05.383+0100"))
            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("power_total").field("myField"))

    val result: SearchResponse = client
      .prepareSearch("myIndex")
      .setTypes("myType")
      .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
      .setQuery(query)
      .addAggregation(agg)
      .addSort("Day", SortOrder.DESC)
      .setSize(815)
      .addField("myField")
      .execute()
      .actionGet()

    val results = result.getHits.getHits
        println("Current results: " + results.length)
        for (hit <- results) {
          println("------------------------------")
          val response = hit.getSource
          println(response)
        }
    client.close()
```

RESULT WAS

```
current result = 0
```

Please let me know why am not getting value for "myField" like I got using sense.
I have tried doing it severally and still get same errors, could it be that I don't parse the query response the right way?

Comment: Are you trying to exactly replicate the sense query? If so, for starters, `myIndext` is used there, but `myIndex` in the Scala code

Comment: No check my answer, I put up "myIndex" on purpose not the name I used.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was correct the only pitfall was that I was querying a date time not stored stored in my database. so instead of "2017-01-01", I was inserting this "2017-01-02"